# mysql RANGE partitioning - how do I find partition boundaries?

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I am implementing partitioning support for mysql in [eludia](https://github.com/do-/eludia) engine

I need to compare partitioning description in model with actual database contents and alter table, if necessary.
To extract all partition info about table I use `information_schema.partitions`

```
ALTER TABLE foo PARTITION BY RANGE (is_archive)
(
 PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN 1,
 PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);
SELECT * FROM information_schema.partitions WHERE table_schema = database() AND table_name = 'foo';
```

I've inspected `information_schema.partitions`, it has partition_method, partition_expression but not ranges (`LESS THAN 1`, `LESS THAN MAXVALUE` parts)

I know I can extract this from `SHOW CREATE TABLE`. It is hard way:(

How should I programmatically retrieve partition boundaries in mysql?

Enviroment: mysql 5.1+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure, but [5.1 documentation says](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitions-table.html):

> PARTITION_DESCRIPTION: This column is used for RANGE and LIST
>   partitions. For a RANGE partition, it contains the value set in the
>   partition's VALUES LESS THAN clause, which can be either an integer or
>   MAXVALUE. For a LIST partition, this column contains the values
>   defined in the partition's VALUES IN clause, which is a
>   comma-separated list of integer values.
>
> For partitions whose PARTITION_METHOD is other than RANGE or LIST,
>   this column is always NULL.

In my 5.6 installation I can get:

```
mysql> SELECT PARTITION_NAME, PARTITION_DESCRIPTION FROM information_schema.partitions WHERE table_schema = database() AND table_name = 'foo';
+----------------+-----------------------+
| PARTITION_NAME | PARTITION_DESCRIPTION |
+----------------+-----------------------+
| p0             | 1                     |
| p1             | MAXVALUE              |
+----------------+-----------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Please note than your original `ALTER TABLE` syntax had a problem, and it should be written as:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE foo PARTITION BY RANGE (is_archive) (
         PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (1),
         PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
       );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.12 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```